# Rewrite rule for special character/encoded url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite-module

I'm new to Dotnet and I need redirect below url to home page for SEO. In browser, encode url is changing to html tag and rewrite url is not working. Please help me to fix this.

Example: domain.com/xyz-%3Cb%3Eabc%3C/b%3Eurl

I tried below Rule. Please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="false">
 <match url="^xyz-%3Cb%3Eabc%3C/b%3Eurl$" />
<action type="Redirect" url="/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```